# I'm doing a exercise of a course and when i execute node nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend

I'm using readline for input and when i execute nothing happens, someone can give a light?
I was using in the same file for every exercise propose, i look here at stackoverflow and i was thinking i'm doing right but lol n i'm using windows.

This is my code

```
const { rejects } = require('assert');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const question1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rl.question('Qual a temperatura hoje: '), (cel) => {
            var fah = cel * 1.8 + 32;
            console.log(`A temperatura em fahrenheit é ${fah}!`);

            resolve();
        };
    })
}


const question2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var dia = "";
        rl.question('Qual é o dia da semana em número?: ', (dia) => {

            switch (dia) {
                case 1:
                    console.log("Domingo!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    console.log("Segunda!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    console.log("Terça");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    console.log("Quarta");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    console.log("Quinta");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    console.log("Sexta!");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    console.log("Sabado");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Dia inválido!");
                    break;
            }
            console.log(`A temperatura em fahrenheit é ${fah}!`);

            resolve();
        });
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    await question1()
    await question2()
    // await question3()
    // await question4()
    // await question5()
    // await question6()
    // await question7()
    // await question8()
    rl.close()
}

main()
```

And i'm expecting that it execute!

Answer (score 3):

Syntax error @line: `rl.question('Qual a temperatura hoje: '), (cel) => {`
Misplaced `)` character after first string argument to function call.
(You've also forgotten to define fah in question2)

```js
const { rejects } = require('assert');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const question1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rl.question('Qual a temperatura hoje: ', (cel) => {
            var fah = cel * 1.8 + 32;
            console.log(`A temperatura em fahrenheit é ${fah}!`);

            resolve();
        });
    })
}


const question2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var dia = "";
        rl.question('Qual é o dia da semana em número?: ', (dia) => {

            switch (dia) {
                case 1:
                    console.log("Domingo!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    console.log("Segunda!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    console.log("Terça");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    console.log("Quarta");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    console.log("Quinta");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    console.log("Sexta!");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    console.log("Sabado");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Dia inválido!");
                    break;
            }
            console.log(`A temperatura em fahrenheit é ${fah}!`);

            resolve();
        });
    })
}

const main = async () => {
    await question1()
    await question2()
    // await question3()
    // await question4()
    // await question5()
    // await question6()
    // await question7()
    // await question8()
    rl.close()
}

main()
```